# How to prevent selecting deleted IDs when selecting random row from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to select random rows from a product database by their unique id`s.
I need 3-4 random products on every page...

This is how i started

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `products` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id = $offset LIMIT 1" );
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($n>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
        $cod_produs = $row["cod_produs"];
        $nume_produs = $row["nume_produs"];
        $titlul_paginii = $row["titlul_paginii"];
        $nume_intermediar = str_replace (" ", "-", $nume_produs);
        $nou_nume_produs = strtolower($nume_intermediar);
        $detalii = $row["detalii"];
        $seo_descriere = $row["seo_descriere"];
        $materiale = $row["materiale"];
        $numere = $row["numere"];
        $pret = $row["pret"];
        $categorie = $row["categorie"];
        $subcategorie = $row["subcategorie"];
        $data_adaugare = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["data_adaugare"]));

    }

echo ("The id of the product is ".$id." and his name is ".$nume_produs);

    };
  ?>
```

The problem is that my code returns ids that i have deleted over time... how do i prevent doing that?

And how i can return 3 or 4 unique id's at once, and am open to better ways of doing this?

Comment: how do you know if your product is deleted? what is the field/column name in the table that shows if it was deleted?

Comment: I do not have that table ... so i need to crate a table with all my products id that i will delete or i deleted ?

Comment: no just add a new column name it `deleted` and set value 1 to deleted products. i will post the answer here

Comment: i understand, but the problem is that when i have deleted an product from the website... i completely delete the record from the database.. it seems that my logic was wrong..

Comment: then just do this: `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your script, do this:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM `products`");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object($offset_result); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT $offset, 1");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

But this will return only one record. you can get consecutive records or you have to run it many times.

```
$offset_result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `products`");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object($offset_result); 

$total = (($offset_row->total) - 1);
$range_arr = range(0, $total);
shuffle($range_arr);
$off_1 = $range_arr[0];
$off_2 = $range_arr[1];
$off_3 = $range_arr[2];

$result = mysql_query(" (SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT $off_1, 1)
                        UNION
                        (SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT $off_2, 1)
                        UNION
                        (SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT $off_3, 1)");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I do not want to use order by rand.. because is very slow.. and not recommended for big tables...

Comment: oh! ok now it's clear. you should've be clear in your question. i will  edit my answer.

Comment: @Gustonez, your last approach don't solve deleted id's problem. If `$off_2` is not yet in database no row are returned.

Comment: i am not getting the record by id here. i am only limiting the results.

Comment: Yes, i had a mistake there.. and by changing this row $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT $offset, 3"); with 3 at the end.. i see that i get 3 results.. thank you very much

Comment: welcome. but you can get non consecutive records by trying my second suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The usualy way is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

You can read explanation at [Selecting random record from MySQL database table.](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/)

For your code:

```
mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3" );
```

**Edited due OP comment**

Then, you can get a subset of data. Modifying your code:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( "SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id) * RAND() - 1000) AS `offset` 
                               FROM `products` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `products` 
                         WHERE id between $offset and $offset + 1000
                         ORDER BY RAND() 
                         LIMIT 0,3" );
```

And the fast solution is to get 3 randoms ID's:

```
$randoms_id = '-1';
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {

  $id_result = mysql_query( " SELECT id FROM `products` 
                              WHERE id >= 
                                  (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) 
                                   FROM `products` ) 
                              ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;");
  $id_row = mysql_fetch_object( $id_result ); 
  $id = $id_row->id;

  $randoms_id = $randoms_id . ',' . $id;
}
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `products` 
                         WHERE id in ($randoms_id);")
```

Comment: As i know ORDER BY RAND() is slow for big tables... and it`s not recomanded to use...

Comment: @user1483138, fixed in answer. Sorry about PHP syntax errors, not used to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer's, you have a mistake there... i fix it at $id = ... it must be $id= $id_row->id... the first part it`s working well.. but it returns only small values... and the second part.. returns sometime the same id twice... thank you. I managed to solve the problem

Comment: ok. fixed first mistake. I don't know why returns small values. Perhaps with few debug you can fix the issue. Please, post it here to write a final answer. Thanks!